# Update time not working! what or where should I put the update syntax?

Tags: php, sql

I wanted to get the login time of the user when he logs in I don't know if I'm putting the update syntax in proper place or not? Here's my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
    session_start ();   

    unset ($_SESSION['username']);
?>

    <html>
    <style type="text/css">
    body{
        float: right;
        padding-top: 150px;
        padding-right: 200px;
    }
    form{

        padding-top: 60px;
        padding-left: 50px;
        width: 300px;
    }
    #login_wrap{

        background-color: #a1bdb8;
        padding-top: 10px;
        height: 300px;
        width: 400px;

        border-radius: 17px 17px 17px 17px;
        -moz-border-radius: 17px 17px 17px 17px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 17px 17px 17px 17px;
        border: 0px solid #000000;

        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    }

    </style>
        <head>
            <link rel="shortcut icon" href="image/favicon.ico">
            <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css">
        </head>
        <body>
            <main id="login_wrap">
                <div id="login">
                    <form name="login" role="form" method="post">
                        <input class="form-control" name="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" required><br>
                        <input class="form-control" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" required><br>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="button">Log-in</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </main>
        </body>
    <?php
         $conn = new mysqli('localhost','root',' ','dole_transac_system') or die ('connection error');
         if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
            header('Location:check_maker.php');
         }else{

         }
         if(isset($_POST['button'])){

         $user = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : '';
         $pass = isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : '';
         $query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM login_info WHERE username = '$user' and password = '$pass'");
         $row = mysqli_num_rows($query);
         if ($row == 1) {
            date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Singapore');
            $dateTime = date('Y-m-d');
            $loginTime = mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE login_info SET dateTime = '$dateTime' WHERE username = '$username'");
            $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
            header('Location:check_maker.php');
         }else{
            echo "<br><font color='red'>Error</font>";
         }
        }
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function submitForm() {
          $("#login").reset();
          return false;
          }
    </script>
    </html>
```

Comment: Can you print that query and execute in phpMyAdmin ? Print this part  : UPDATE login_info SET dateTime = '$dateTime' WHERE username = '$username'

Comment: do you mean to echo out the result?

Comment: Yes, echo the string and see what comes in it and then execute that query in phpmyadmin

Comment: done, i tried the code in different file with if condition to see if the query is working and the result is the query is actually not working i dont know why?

Comment: echo the generated query as @Anjum said and run it in phpMyAdmin. What error do you get?

Comment: the query will always return int 1 i guess?

Comment: but i will try anyway just to see what error i get

Comment: Is there any error when you run the query in phpymyadmin ?

Comment: I suppose `WHERE username = '$username'` should be `WHERE username = '$user'` because there is no variable called `$username` in your script.

Comment: ok, do two things, first remove "date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Singapore');"   And also check what is the data type of dateTime in your database. Also change column name dateTime because i think this is reserve word